# Core data causing miss layout

Tags: swift, core-data, ios-autolayout

I have a generic viewModel that handles core data delegations. But when I insert a new data to the context core data gives me a weird error:

```
[error] fault: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to delete row 1 from section 1 which only contains 1 rows before the update with userInfo (null)
CoreData: fault: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to delete row 1 from section 1 which only contains 1 rows before the update with userInfo (null)
```

I don't delete any of the rows. Actually I'm just inserting. Here is my viewModel's delegation

```
func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    delegate?.endUpdates()
}

func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    delegate?.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .insert:
        if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
            delegate?.insertItemAt(indexPath: newIndexPath)
        }
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            delegate?.insertItemAt(indexPath: indexPath)
        }
    case .delete:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            delegate?.deleteItemAt(indexPath: indexPath)
        }
    case .move:
        if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
            delegate?.insertItemAt(indexPath: newIndexPath)
        }

        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            delegate?.deleteItemAt(indexPath: indexPath)
        }
    case .update:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            delegate?.updateItemAt(indexPath: indexPath)
        }
    }
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    let indexSet: IndexSet = IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex)
    switch type {
    case .insert:
        delegate?.insertSection(indexSet: indexSet)
    case .delete:
        delegate?.deleteSection(indexSet: indexSet)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Here is the ViewController that responds to actions

```
extension ChatVC: CoreDataViewModelDelegate {
func insertSection(indexSet: IndexSet) {
    tableView.insertSections(indexSet, with: .automatic)
}

func deleteSection(indexSet: IndexSet) {
    tableView.deleteSections(indexSet, with: .automatic)
}

func beginUpdates() {
    tableView.beginUpdates() 
}

func endUpdates() {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func insertItemAt(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    tableView.scrollToBottom(animated: true)
    viewModel.sendReadACKForMessageAt(indexPath: indexPath)
}

func deleteItemAt(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}

func updateItemAt(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
}
```

As far as I know, the core data should handle most of the table view actions. I mean when I pop the screen and push the same VC to the navigation everything works fine. I couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: Try logging your calls — something might be being called that you don’t expect.

Comment: I tried to add break point to the delete but it never hits that point. But I will log it. The awkward thing is it is not repeated after the first data